# Is possible extract the original script P2MS from the transaction locked with the P2SH address?

Tags: script, multi-signature, signature, p2sh, input-script

This is a stupid question because if the P2SH contains the hash160 (and the hash160 contains the sha256) of the P2MS doesn't possible return to the original hex P2MS.

So, but for verifying the P2SH I must insert the real redmee script inside the scriptSig, so if I parsing the scriptSing I can found the N signature and the M "public key" inside the script P2MS, right?

An example, inside an scientific article [this address](https://blockstream.info/address/3CD1QW6fjgTwKq3Pj97nty28WZAVkziNom) is cataloged such as scam address, but this address is a script address, so it could is:

- a P2MS script with M "public keys"
- a script without the "public keys"

But I can access the scriptSig and parsing the hexadecimal, I should be found the original script, right?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the bare multisig script from a P2SH multisig address?

Comment: I'm trying to validate my idea, i.e the "public key" push inside the P2MS script can be extracted to parsing the scriptSig of the transaction unlock it.